# System.InvalidOperationException: Compiler executable file csc.exe cannot be found

Tags: .net, .net-framework-version

I have an application in .NET 4.0 framework.

This application was running fine on server with .NET framework 4.0 installed on it (also all previous versions (3.5 sp1, 3.0, 2.0) are installed on this machine). For some reason we have to move this application to another server which only has .NET framework 4.5.2 installed on it. So as soon as after moving application to this new server when we access it, we are having this error message:

> Compiler executable file csc.exe cannot be found.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Compiler executable file csc.exe cannot be found.

I am not able to determine what's causing this problem. Please suggest.

Here is complete stack trace:

```
[InvalidOperationException: Compiler executable file csc.exe cannot be found.]
   System.CodeDom.Compiler.RedistVersionInfo.GetCompilerPath(IDictionary`2 provOptions, String compilerExecutable) +8338603
   Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.FromFileBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] fileNames) +739
   Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.System.CodeDom.Compiler.ICodeCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromFileBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] fileNames) +170
   System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile() +12114384
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild() +301
   System.Web.Compilation.ApplicationBuildProvider.GetGlobalAsaxBuildResult(Boolean isPrecompiledApp) +12653841
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileGlobalAsax() +50
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() +665

[HttpException (0x80004005): Compiler executable file csc.exe cannot be found.]
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ReportTopLevelCompilationException() +80
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() +1142
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +1193

[HttpException (0x80004005): Compiler executable file csc.exe cannot be found.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +12656404
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +159
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +12496021
```

Comment: Well, does "csc.exe" exist in either C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319 or C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319?

Comment: @vcsjones: yes it does exist there.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same issue in windows app, i just simply reinstalled Dot net framework, and it works for me.